# Tutorials/Books detailing JQUERY, AJAX, CSS (how technologies integrate)

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Any recomendations on how these technolgoies work together to create dynamic HTML pages would be beneficial.  I wanted to find one source of documentation which details the relationship between the above technologies.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not sure that you're going to find one quality source to cover all of those subjects. They're all pretty distinct and you can go into great depth on each subject. I'm assuming that you're looking to learn/give someone else the tools to learn basic web development?

This site seems to accompany an Apress book and has some very useful CSS examples. http://cssdesignpatterns.com/

With HTML/CSS and learning JavaScript/CSS patterns, there's nothing better than just viewing sources/using Firebug or other developer tools to inspect sites and see how others have built things.

As for jQuery, you *can* use it without truly understanding the JavaScript underneath, but you will get much, much further in being able to create the sites that you want to create if you have at least a rudimentary knowledge of JavaScript proper. Though rather opinionated (in many spots this is a good thing) Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts" is a solid intro to JS. http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/ 
Otherwise, you could pick up any intro to JS book - I'd recommend an O'Reilly book. There are other good ones I'm sure, but O'Reilly is almost always a safe bet. Looks like a JS/jQuery book is coming out next month if you can wait. http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920015048

Any JS/jQuery book should probably cover AJAX. The API docs for jQuery at api.jquery.com are a great resource.

In terms of the relationship between these technologies: HTML should be thought of as the semantic context for your content that contains anchors (IDs, classes) for CSS to style elements and for JavaScript to alter those elements dynamically. jQuery is a JS library that allows you to write JavaScript more quickly and easily. AJAX, via JavaScript, allows you to load data sources into your page. This explanation is admittedly a bit of a simplification, but should be sufficient context to start with.